# Instantiating a constructor function repeats existing array items pushed from previous instantiation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a constructor function name `Book` and an empty array named `myLibrary` as a container for these new book object instances.  A separate function to create a book `createBook` calls a function `addBookToLibrary` which pushes the book into the `myLibrary` array, clears the form to add books, then renders the book list via the `viewBookList` function.

Each time I call `createBook` and create a new instance of `Book`, I'm running into a problem where the rendered list of books that show up on the page repeat all instances of `Book` objects created prior to the new book being added plus the one new book. For instance, I have book1, book2 and book3 that I previously created.  I then add book4 so now the array has [ {book1...}, {book2...}, {book3...}, {book4...} ] objects correctly in place, but what's being rendered on the page is a scattered mess of book1, book1, book2, book1, book2, book3, book1, book2, book3, book4 as you see in the attached image. You'll see the array in the console is fine.

[image: image of book container]

I initially cleared out the `myLibrary` array in createBook which correctly rendered the books to the page, but obviously wipes out my array which won't work because I need to be able to delete these at some point from the array. So my question is, how do I display what's in my array onto the page each time without rendering duplicates of books that were already added?

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');
const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector('.open-modal');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const modalElement = document.querySelector('.modal');

// let myLibrary = [
//   new Book('Down and Out in Paris and London', 'George Orwell', 232, true),
//   new Book('Homage to Catalonia', 'George Orwell', 202, true),
//   new Book('Shooting an Elephant', 'George Orwell', 368, false),
// ];
// let count = myLibrary.length - 3;

let myLibrary = [];
let count = myLibrary.length;

// Constructor...
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = Number(pages);
  this.read = Boolean(read);

  // Methods
  this.bookInfo = function () {
    const wasRead = this.read === true ? 'read' : 'not read';
    return `${this.title} written by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages in length was ${wasRead}.`;
  };

  return this.bookInfo();
}

function createBook(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // myLibrary = [];

  let title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  let author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  let pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
  let read = document.querySelector('#read').value;

  // Instantiate new Book object
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read); // Add ID when instantiating
  addBookToLibrary(newBook);
  clearForm();
  viewBookList(myLibrary);
}

function addBookToLibrary(book) {
  // Hide modal
  removeClass();
  // Add book to array
  return myLibrary.push(book);
}

function clearForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').reset();
}

function setCardStyle(element, details) {
  element.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; text-align: center; background-color: #fff; padding: 1em; margin: 1em 1em 1em 0; border-radius: 5px; height: 250px; width: 250px; line-height: 1.5; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);',
  );

  element.innerHTML = `
    <h3 class="title">${details.title}</h3>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p>${details.author}</p>
    <p>${details.pages} pages</p>
    <p>${details.read === true ? 'Read' : 'Unread'}</p>`;
}

function createCard() {
  let bookCard = document.createElement('div');
  bookCard.classList.add('card');
  bookCard.setAttribute('data-target', `${count++}`); // Set target ID

  return bookCard;
}

function removeBookBtn() {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  // Style button
  btn.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'color: red; height: 2.5em; width: 50%; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0 auto; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; cursor: pointer;',
  );
  btn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  return btn;
}

function handleDelete(e) {
  // Get book's data-target
  let bookIndex = parseInt(e.path[1].attributes[1].value);
  // console.log(bookIndex);

  myLibrary.splice(bookIndex, 1);
  // console.log(newArray);
  // myLibrary = myLibrary.filter((book, index) => index !== bookIndex);
  return viewBookList(myLibrary);
}

function clearDOM(element) {
  while (element.firstElementChild) {
    element.firstElementChild.remove();
  }
}

function viewBookList(list) {
  const bookDiv = document.querySelector('.book-list');
  clearDOM(bookDiv);

  for (book in list) {
    let bookDetails = list[book];
    let renderCard = createCard();
    const deleteButton = removeBookBtn();

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', handleDelete);
    setCardStyle(renderCard, bookDetails);

    renderCard.appendChild(deleteButton);
    bookDiv.appendChild(renderCard);
  }

  return bookDiv;
}

function addClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.add('open');
}

function removeClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.remove('open');
}

// Event listeners
btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', addClass);
btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', removeClass);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', createBook);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

:root {
  --roboto: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  --pt: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: var(--roboto);
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a6c1ee 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #000;
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.btn {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.open-modal {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


.modal.open {
  display: flex;
}

.form {
  padding: 5em;
}


.modal-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.modal.open .modal-container {
  animation: move 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

.close-modal {
  font-size: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s linear;
}

.close-modal:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.book-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  gap: 2em;
}

/* Created in app.js */
/* .card {
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <script src="scripts/app.js" defer></script>
  <title>Odin Library</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Library</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="modal open">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <span id="close-modal" class="close-modal">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="bookForm" id="form" class="form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="title" class="label">title: </label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Animal Farm" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="author" class="label">author: </label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="George Orwell" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="pages" class="label">pages: </label>
            <input type="number" name="pages" id="pages" placeholder="232" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="read" class="label">read: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="read" id="read" required>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit" class="submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section class="card-section">
    <section>
      <!-- Add plus icon -->
      <button class="btn open-modal" id="open-modal">Add Book</button> 
      <div class="book-list">
        <!-- Container for cards -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you ever clear your book list DOM? I only see appending new elelemnts. Perhaps `viewBookList` should first clear out the container of all children?

Comment: Nothing to do with constructors, nothing to do with array pushing. `viewBookList` simply always adds all items you give it to the page. The previous things on the page are not cleared.

Comment: @CollinD I took your advice and added a separate function ```clearDOM``` to clear the DOM and called it in ```viewBookList```.  Updated the code snippet as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others already said on the comment, the problem is that each time you add a new book, when you try to display ti on the page you are "appending" all the books after the already existing books.

So you get something like this:
Add book 1: (1)
Add book 2: (1) (1 2)
Add book 3: (1) (1 2) (1 2 3)

The solution is to clear the container div before you update it.

Something like this (JS line 107):

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');
const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector('.open-modal');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const modalElement = document.querySelector('.modal');

// let myLibrary = [
//   new Book('Down and Out in Paris and London', 'George Orwell', 232, true),
//   new Book('Homage to Catalonia', 'George Orwell', 202, true),
//   new Book('Shooting an Elephant', 'George Orwell', 368, false),
// ];
// let count = myLibrary.length - 3;

let myLibrary = [];
let count = myLibrary.length;

// Constructor...
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = Number(pages);
  this.read = Boolean(read);

  // Methods
  this.bookInfo = function() {
    const wasRead = this.read === true ? 'read' : 'not read';
    return `${this.title} written by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages in length was ${wasRead}.`;
  };

  return this.bookInfo();
}

function createBook(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // myLibrary = [];

  let title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  let author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  let pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
  let read = document.querySelector('#read').value;

  // Instantiate new Book object
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read); // Add ID when instantiating
  addBookToLibrary(newBook);
  clearForm();
  viewBookList(myLibrary);
}

function addBookToLibrary(book) {
  // Hide modal
  removeClass();
  // Add book to array
  return myLibrary.push(book);
}

function clearForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').reset();
}

function setCardStyle(element, details) {
  element.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; text-align: center; background-color: #fff; padding: 1em; margin: 1em 1em 1em 0; border-radius: 5px; height: 250px; width: 250px; line-height: 1.5; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);',
  );

  element.innerHTML = `
    <h3 class="title">${details.title}</h3>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p>${details.author}</p>
    <p>${details.pages} pages</p>
    <p>${details.read === true ? 'Read' : 'Unread'}</p>`;
}

function createCard() {
  let bookCard = document.createElement('div');
  bookCard.classList.add('card');
  bookCard.setAttribute('data-target', `${count++}`); // Set target ID

  return bookCard;
}

function removeBookBtn() {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  // Style button
  btn.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'color: red; height: 2.5em; width: 50%; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0 auto; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; cursor: pointer;',
  );
  btn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  return btn;
}

function handleDelete(e) {
  // Get book's data-target
  let bookIndex = parseInt(e.path[1].attributes[1].value);
  // console.log(bookIndex);

  myLibrary.splice(bookIndex, 1);
  // console.log(newArray);
  // myLibrary = myLibrary.filter((book, index) => index !== bookIndex);
  return viewBookList(myLibrary);
}

function viewBookList(list) {
  const bookDiv = document.querySelector('.book-list');
  bookDiv.innerHTML = "";
  console.log(myLibrary);

  for (book in list) {
    let bookDetails = list[book];
    let renderCard = createCard();
    const deleteButton = removeBookBtn();

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', handleDelete);
    setCardStyle(renderCard, bookDetails);

    renderCard.appendChild(deleteButton);
    bookDiv.appendChild(renderCard);
  }

  return bookDiv;
}

function addClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.add('open');
}

function removeClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.remove('open');
}

// Event listeners
btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', addClass);
btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', removeClass);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', createBook);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
:root {
  --roboto: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  --pt: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: var(--roboto);
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a6c1ee 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #000;
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.btn {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.open-modal {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
}

.form {
  padding: 5em;
}

.modal-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.modal.open .modal-container {
  animation: move 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

.close-modal {
  font-size: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s linear;
}

.close-modal:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.book-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  gap: 2em;
}


/* Created in app.js */


/* .card {
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <script src="scripts/app.js" defer></script>
  <title>Odin Library</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Library</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="modal open">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <span id="close-modal" class="close-modal">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="bookForm" id="form" class="form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="title" class="label">title: </label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Animal Farm" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="author" class="label">author: </label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="George Orwell" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="pages" class="label">pages: </label>
            <input type="number" name="pages" id="pages" placeholder="232" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="read" class="label">read: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="read" id="read" required>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit" class="submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section class="card-section">
    <section>
      <!-- Add plus icon -->
      <button class="btn open-modal" id="open-modal">Add Book</button>
      <div class="book-list">
        <!-- Container for cards -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I took your advice but slightly modified it to include a function clearDOM to clear out the DOM.  Marked your answer as the accepted answer either way.

Comment: Nice. I think it would be a good idea to change the `function Book` into a `class Book`. In the end it doesn't make a big difference, it is just a cleaner and more modern way of doing it

Comment: took your advice and converted it to a class.